# Prevent local shell from replacing variables when sending ssh commands

Tags: linux, bash, shell, ssh

I try to send an SSH command to a remote server. The command is either issued directly in the shell (bash) or from a Makefile:

```
ssh me@server "rsync -avz /my/stuff $SCRATCH/my/stuff"
```

`$SCRATCH` is an environment variable on the remote server, and properly set there. But unfortunately, my local system will try to replace `$SCRATCH` by a local environment variable before sending the SSH command.

**How can I prevent that?**

Comment: Use single quotes instead of double.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Escape `$` sign with a backslash to prevent local variable expansion:

```
ssh me@server "rsync -avz /my/stuff \$SCRATCH/my/stuff"
```